# Looking for a method to solve simple trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry

Assume that $N$, $q$, $k_1$ and $k_2$ are integers such that 
$N>1$, $0\leq k_1<k_2<N$ and $q\geq 3$.

Is there a method to solve the following trigonometric equation:

$$
\sin\big(\frac{\pi k_1}{N}\big)\sin\big(\frac{\pi k_2}{N}\big)=\pm \cos\big(\frac{\pi}{q}\big)
$$

Thanks

Comment: @ Yves Daoust: the unknowns are the unknowns, namely $N$, $q$, $k_1$ and $k_2$...

Comment: Easy case: $k_1=\frac N2\implies\sin(\frac{\pi k_2}N)=\pm\cos(\frac{\pi}k)$.